# Android Market (Google Play). Get buyer information

Tags: android, google-checkout, google-play

I want to publish a PAID app on the market but first I'd like to find out if it's possible to at least see an email address of each person who bought my app. I'd like a way of possibly contacting some of them (no, i don't want to send spam or such).

Is this possible? Someone told me that in Google Checkout you can see each buyers detailed information which also contains an email address. Is this true?

Please excuse the fact that it's not a programming question, but it's still related to software development.

Thank you very much,

Andrei

Comment: why don't you add a registration page... whoever has bought it will definitely register... ask for whatever information you want in the registration page.

Comment: Because i only need the information for the people who bought my app, and not downloaded it illegally :P But yes, i'll use that method in case I won't be able to do it the way i describe above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Checkout usually shows buyer information, including e-mail and registered street address, so you can send an e-mail or usual snail mail.

However, most of the time profile shown has `Email Marketing: No` written below and I would think twice before trying to contact people at will.

Comment: I'd like to know if you're saying this from personal experience. I mean, are you an Android developer and have personally seen the buyers  information? :) I just want to be 100% sure. ALSO: you said "usually" show, so the email address doesn't appear for everyone?

Comment: And one other thing thing: "Email Marketing: No", bu that doesn't stop me from sending them a message, no? The email address is still visible. No ?

Comment: I'm talking from personal experience. In my case 100% of buyers have e-mail shown on the Orders page, and about 80% of them have valid postal address. `Email Marketing: NO` won't stop you from sending e-mail, but people may complain about it.

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much. Could you also check out this other question? I'm guessing you might know how to answer this one as well. :) Thank you again. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267339/android-market-google-checkout-and-bank-account

Comment: Buyer info has gone with Google wallet unfortunately now