# Android Market. Google Checkout and Bank account

Tags: android, google-checkout, google-play

Please excuse the fact that it's not a programming question, but it's still related to software development, so i hope it is ok.

Creating an Android developer account for paid apps implies registering a GoogleCheckout account which in turn implies linking it to a bank account from one of those 31 eligible countries.

Can someone please clarify for me some aspects regarding Google Checkout and the bank which is linked to the GC account? So here are a couple of questions:

1. If i'm not mistaken i read somewhere that you can checkout only at the end of every month. My question is: does Google automatically wire the money from the GC account into you Bank account? OR you can keep the money in your GC for as long as you want and manually choose when and how much money to transfer to your bank account?
2. If you can do it manually, then can you choose NOT to transfer the money from the GC account into your bank account, but instead transfer it to a PayPal account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Money is transferred automatically on the second day of every month. There are no settings to change nor time nor amount of the transfer, all earnings for the previous month come to you no matter what.
2. Google insists on banking account, no Paypal, sorry. And after you enter the necessary information Google does special check to make sure it's your account by (nice surprise =) **depositing** $1 to your account and asking about details of that deposit.

Comment: you may reach me in skype as `lenik.terenin`, if you need more details or have more questions. i might even speak your language =)

Comment: This is great. Thank you again. I'm from Romania, and your name doesn't sound Romanian, so i don't think you speak my language :) But nevertheless, i'll accept your "offer" and I'll add you on Skype in a bit.